# jQuery cant read words after a space in attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

This is a script for a dropdown search menu/filter in Carto. This script seems to work fine up until the point where the sql query is being set. Whenever there is a space in one of the attribute names, the script only finds the first word and thus there is no match in the database. Like "San Deigo" will only return "San." The value of the variable "input" is only the first word. If the attribute does not have spaces, the script works fine.

Could this be a problem with select to or is there something else wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Searchbox + Dropdown menu + Zoom + CARTO.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script> 

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #wraper-city-selector {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
      }
      .js-city-selector {
        width: 175px;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- map div -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- selector div -->
    <div id="wraper-city-selector">
      <select class="js-city-selector">
        <option value="#" selected disabled>Select a city</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- legend div -->
    <div class='cartodb-legend category'>
      <div class="legend-title" style="color:#284a59">Cities</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#5F4690"></div>Populated Place</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#1D6996"></div>Admin. 1 Capital</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#38A6A5"></div>Admin. 0 Capital</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#0F8554"></div>Admin. 1 region Capital</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#73AF48"></div>Scientific Station</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#EDAD08"></div>Admin. O region Capital </li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#E17C05"></div>Admin. 0 Capital Alt.</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#CC503E"></div>Historic Place</li>
          <li><div class="bullet" style="background-color:#94346E"></div>Meteorological Station</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    <script type="text/cartocss" id="style">
      #layer {
        marker-width: 10;
        marker-fill: ramp([featurecla], (#5F4690, #1D6996, #38A6A5, #0F8554, #73AF48, #EDAD08, #E17C05, #CC503E, #94346E), ("Populated place", "Admin-1 capital", "Admin-0 capital", "Admin-1 region capital", "Scientific station", "Admin-0 region capital", "Admin-0 capital alt", "Historic place", "Meteorological Station"), "=");
        marker-fill-opacity: 0.7;
        marker-allow-overlap: true;
        marker-line-width: 0;
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/sql" id="query">
      SELECT * FROM populated_places WHERE pop_max > 700000
    </script>

    <script>
      function main() {

        // get selector
        var selector = $(".js-city-selector");

        // get styles & query
           style = $("#style").text(),
            query = $("#query").text(),

        // declare map variable
            map = L.map('map', { 
                  zoomControl: false,
                  center: [41, -3],
                  zoom: 3
                  });

        // add basemap
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'}).addTo(map);

        // add cartodb layer
        cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          user_name: 'ramirocartodb',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
            sql: query,
            cartocss: style,
          }]
        }).addTo(map)
        .done(function(layer){

          // declare sublayer variable
          var cityLayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

          // populate selector with city names from sublayer data
          var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'ramirocartodb' });
          sql.execute(query)
            .done(function(data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.total_rows; i++) {

                var name = data.rows[i].name;

                selector.append("<option value=" + name + ">" + name + "</option>");
              }
            });

          selector.select2();

          // filter & zoom cities when selecting an option from selector
          selector.change(function(){

            var input = $( ".js-city-selector option:selected" ).val(); 

            console.log("You have selected " + input + ".");

            cityLayer.setSQL(query + " AND name ilike '" + input + "'");

             sql.getBounds(query + " AND name ilike '" + input + 
             "'")
             .done(function(bounds) {

             map.fitBounds(bounds);
             map.setZoom(16);

            });


          });
        });
      }
    window.onload = main;
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem line is

```
selector.append("<option value=" + name + ">" + name + "</option>");
```

You need to wrap the attributes in quotes

```
selector.append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
```

```js
var name = "San Deigo";
$('select').append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');

name = "los angeles";
$('select').append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');


$('select').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
</select>
```